# Replacing specific values in a data frame column according to multiple conditions in other columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements

I'm a relative beginner with R so apologies for the simplistic question.

I have a simple data frame with columns x, y and z. They all contain numerical values and I'd like to write a piece of code that allows me to replaces a all z values with "115" whenever 300 < x < 600, 0 < y < 100, and z > 160.

Very simple problem but I am not sure why I am having so much trouble figuring out how to piece together code for this. I'm sure its some hodge-podge of replace and ifelse arguments but I can't seem to put it together.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Some of the answers already provided were able to give me the help I needed! Thank you though!

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data_frame("x" = sample(x = 200:700, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 "y" = sample(x = 0:400, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 "z" = sample(x = 0:200, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
df
#> A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1   523    84   109
#> 2   366   276   164
#> 3   328   361    33
#> 4   617   329   105
#> 5   670   262   125
#> 6   498   328    88
#> 7   469    78   171
#> 8   665   212    32
#> 9   386    36    83
#>10   506   104   162

df$z <- ifelse((df$x > 300 & df$x < 600) & (df$y > 0 & df$y < 100) & (df$z > 160), 115, df$z)
df
#> A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1   523    84   109
#> 2   366   276   164
#> 3   328   361    33
#> 4   617   329   105
#> 5   670   262   125
#> 6   498   328    88
#> 7   469    78   115
#> 8   665   212    32
#> 9   386    36    83
#>10   506   104   162

#(#7 was updated to 115 as it met all the criteria)
```

### Edit

As usual, @TIC's answer is better than mine (fewer steps -> faster) but not by much on my system with a million rows. The data.table method is quickest:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data_frame("x" = sample(x = 0:700, size = 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                 "y" = sample(x = 0:400, size = 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                 "z" = sample(x = 0:200, size = 1000000, replace = TRUE))

ifelse_func <- function(df){
  df$z <- ifelse((df$x > 300 & df$x < 600) & (df$y > 0 & df$y < 100) & (df$z > 160), 115, df$z)
}

transform_func <- function(df){
  transform(df, z = replace(z, 300 < x & x < 600 & 0 < y & y < 100 & z > 160, 115))
}

rowsums_func <- function(df){
  df$z[!rowSums(!(df >list(300, 0, 160) & df < list(600, 100, Inf)))] <- 115
}

library(data.table)
dt_func <- function(df){
  setDT(df)
  df[x > 300 & x < 600 & y > 0 & y < 100 & z > 160, z := 115]
}

mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ifelse_func(df), transform_func(df),
                                      rowsums_func(df), dt_func(df))
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image: example_2.png]

### Edit 2

```
> system.time(ifelse_func(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.064   0.020   0.085 
> system.time(transform_func(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.060   0.009   0.069 
> system.time(rowsums_func(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.090   0.021   0.110 
> system.time(dt_func(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.036   0.003   0.039
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Frustrated to see that I was nearly there with my own code but couldn't quite put it together! Thanks for smoothing out the details, really helped me out!

Comment: I think I figured it out @akrun - in your benchmark the dataframe isn't passed to the function i.e. `system.time(rowsums_func)` vs `system.time(rowsums_func(df))`

Comment: Thanks.  that was a typo.  it makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
transform(
  df,
  z = replace(z, 300 < x & x < 600 & 0 < y & y < 100 & z > 160, 115)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

So we can do this with an `ifelse` conditions:

Some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(450, runif(10)*200),
                 y=c(50, runif(10)*100),
                 z=c(170, runif(10)*100))

> df
           x        y         z
1  450.00000 50.00000 170.00000
2   10.38674 93.33277  74.72619
3  117.66350 48.88015  27.60769
4  128.85086 35.74645  61.32745
5   93.21923 87.15894  53.37949
6   30.09869 86.72846  94.64611
7  104.03966 55.12932  89.78309
8   17.48741 16.50095  42.26284
9  183.52845 39.65171  27.60766
10  79.68355 18.14510  84.17454
11 110.14051 77.85835  33.67199
```

Then run this:

```
df$z <- ifelse(df$x > 300 & df$x < 600 & df$y > 0 & df$y < 100 & df$z > 160, 115, df$z)
```

And we get this:

```
> df
           x        y         z
1  450.00000 50.00000 115.00000
2   10.38674 93.33277  74.72619
3  117.66350 48.88015  27.60769
4  128.85086 35.74645  61.32745
5   93.21923 87.15894  53.37949
6   30.09869 86.72846  94.64611
7  104.03966 55.12932  89.78309
8   17.48741 16.50095  42.26284
9  183.52845 39.65171  27.60766
10  79.68355 18.14510  84.17454
11 110.14051 77.85835  33.67199
```

Comment: Yep! This was exactly what I was looking for. You and @jared_mamrot came up with pretty much the same solution and it worked perfectly. Really appreciate it!!

Comment: Great minds think alike! (And as my Mum would add, "and fools' seldom differ" ). Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Another option in `base R` is with `rowSums`

```
df$z[!rowSums(!(df >list(300, 0, 160) & df < list(600, 100, Inf)))] <- 115
```